# Do I need an internet connection to update iOS on my PC?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-update

I've downloaded the IOS5 IPSW from Apple's site and want to update it from within iTunes. So,

- Does the update require an Internet connection?
- Does the iPhone switch off/reboot just as the update is initiated?

I ask because I'm at my new place where I'm yet to setup an Internet connection & my iPhone tethered to my laptop is my only Internet connection. I don't want my phone to be bricked because it cannot verify the update or what-not because there's no Internet connection.

Comment: Well, I'd be glad to test this in 80 minutes when my download finally finishes!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. It has to verify the firmware with Apple's servers (gs.apple.com). If it cannot, it will error out (usually presenting a 3XXX error, which is quite often 3004) and fail to update.

Comment: The question really is: Does iTunes do this? Or does the phone?

I neglected to test appropriately, so sorry, Sathya!

Comment: iTunes. It's your computer that checks for a connection (if you want to test it, enter `0.0.0.0 gs.apple.com` in your hosts file and try to re-install iOS). The iPhone is being prepped for loading, it can't negotiate any kind of connection at that point. So using it's network connection is a no-go. You need the actual computer you are using to load the firmware to have a working connection to the Internet.

Comment: @Sathya No problem. There is no way to bypass the server verification (TinyUmbrella *may* do it but it might also funnel it through its own server, so not local either). It's just one of the many checks Apple puts into iOS to ensure security (and prevent jailbreaking).

Answer (score -3):

it does require internet. Just made the answer short.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem, address the question, or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  Shortest is not always the best.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.